# Wait for event in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have two Dialogs. /test is triggered by the user (luis)
Then it should move to the second /help, and when it gets the event there is should go back to /test and continue there.
Problem is it doesn't wait for the event to be triggered to return to /test, even though end dialog in /help should be only triggered after event.

My use case is I want to let the user login if he want something which requires a auth-token but is not logged in yet and then let him continue with his initial request after the login using a facebook webview is done.
So the user should stay in "Login" until the event arrives that he was successfully logged in and then continue with the /getUserdata.

Anyone has an idea how to solve that? Is bot.on the wrong approch here?

```
bot.dialog('/getUserData', function (session, args, next) {
        session.beginDialog("/Login");
        [...make request for user data]
        session.send("This is your user data ${userdata}").endDialog();
    }).triggerAction({ matches: "getUserData" });

bot.dialog('/Login', function (session, args, next) {
    session.send("You need to login for this action");
    [..open facebook webview so user can login]
    bot.on("event", function (event) {
        session.send("2:Successfully logged in").endDialog();
    })
})
```

Comment: By "event" are you talking about the event sent from your site to your bot?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is an event I am sending from my website.

Comment: more concretely I am using [those events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My use case is I want to let the user login if he want something which requires a auth-token but is not logged in yet and then let him continue with his initial request after the login using a facebook webview is done.

Based on your description, [backchannel mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-backchannel) is not the right approach here for this scenario, cause it can't be triggered whenever user wants to login.

Here we can use `beginDialogAction` to attach your login dialog to your original dialog, for more information, please refer to [Handle contextual action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow#handle-contextual-action). After ending your login dialog, it will return control back to your original dialog. For example:

```
bot.beginDialogAction('login', '/login', {matches: /^login/i});
bot.dialog('/login', (session)=>{
    //login
    console.log("handling login...");
    session.endDialog();
});
```

Use this approach, user can begin the login action whenever and after logged in, it will give control back to the last dialog.

Or if you want to force user to login inside a dialog, you can use waterfall steps, and use `beginDialog` to trigger the login dialog in one step, for example:

```
bot.dialog('/login', (session)=>{
    //login
    console.log("handling login...");
    session.endDialog();
});

bot.dialog('checkshoppingcart', [
    (session)=>{
        session.beginDialog('/login');  
    },
    (session, results)=>{
        //second step
    }
]).triggerAction({matches:/^show shopping cart/i});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The first part is not that important to me, because users won't trigger login themself. Also I need the backchannel to get an event from my website to the bot.
But as you are explaining in the second part the solution seems to be to split up /getUserData into a two step waterfall. Just for the sake of completeness I will post my final code as an answer too.

Comment: so how is this done in the composer?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I don't exactly understand why you have these as separate dialogs instead of having /help nested inside /test using a waterfall pattern.  However I can see you are misunderstanding how bot.on should be used.

This explains more
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#on

Its purpose is to register the handler for 'event', so you need to declare it at the top level as below for it to run from within your dialog.

```
bot.dialog('/test', function (session, args, next) {
    session.beginDialog("/help");
    session.send("3: should be last message").endDialog();
}).triggerAction({ matches: "testDialog" });

bot.dialog('/help', function (session, args, next) {
session.send("1");
}).triggerAction({ matches: "testRoute" });

 bot.on("event", function (event) {
    session.send("2:Event triggered").endDialog();
})
```

However, it only handles bot event types, I'm not sure it will be able to get it to handle your login events.

Comment: The reason why I cannot put it into one waterfall is because I need the login at a lot of different places, whenever the user asks for something which needs authentification.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to make it more clear what I want. Basically I want that the user is only sent back to /getUserData if the event is received, because only after he logged in on the webview (so the event is received)  I can give him the requested user Data.
The event I triggered is a standard bot framework event.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer above, this is the code which I ended up working:

```
bot.dialog('/getUserData', [
(session, args, next) => {
    session.beginDialog("/Login1");
},
(session, args, next) => {
    session.send(`This is your token ${session.userData.token}, so getUserData could be handled now`).endDialog();
},
]).triggerAction({ matches: "getUserData" });

bot.dialog('/Login1', (session, args, next) => {
    session.send("You need to login for this action");
    // [..open facebook webview so user can login] and wait for event
    bot.on("event", function (event) {
        session.userData.token = "exampletoken";
        session.send("2:Successfully logged in");
        session.endDialog();
    })
})
```